# Ruby - how to parse dates in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an Rails ActiveRecord group query:

```
a = Product.select("date(date) as date, count(id) as products").group("date(date)").to_a
```

and I want to change the format of all of the dates in the array.  I thought it would be something like this:

```
a.map { |s, i| [Date.parse(s).to_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), i] }
```

However, I am getting a `can't convert Product into String` error. How can I parse the dates in my array and change their format?

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of the output I am looking for.

Given this table:

```
 create_table :products do |t|
       t.date :date
 end
```

Ultimately, I want to create a json output based on the above group query. Something like:

```
 [{"products":23,"date":"2012-06-15T00:00:00"}, {"products":26,"date":"2012-06-16T00:00:00"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
a.map { |s, i| [Date.parse(s.date).to_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), i] }
```

Your query returns an array of `Product` objects with two fake fields `date` and `products` (same as in the SQL query). To get dates you should call `s.date` on the elements of the returned array.

**EDIT**

To get desired array you can do:

```
query_result = Product.select("date(date) as date, count(id) as products").group("date(date)")

query_result.map do |row| 
  { :products => row.products, :date => Date.parse(row.date).to_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") }
end
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked to convert the date.  However, now my array is showing nil for every i value.  For example: `<%= debug a %>` yields `!ruby/object:Product attributes: !binary "ZGF0ZQ==": '2012-05-27' !binary "Y2hlY2t0ZXN0cw==": 1`; however, `<%= a.map { |s, i| [Date.parse(s.date).to_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), i] } %>` yields `[["2012-05-27T00:00:00", nil]]`. Why do the i values change to nil?

Comment: Well, I'm still not sure what you've expected to get in this `i` parameter of the block. [`Array#map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) method passes only a single parameter into the block - current element of the array. For your example that means that you get current `Product` in the `s` parameter and nothing in the second `i` parameter.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My goal is to end up with an array of hashes `a = Product.select("date(date) as date, count(id) as products").group("date(date)").to_a` where instead of the date being formatted as yyyy-mm-dd it is formatted  as yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss. It doesn't have to necessarily use an `Array#map` if that is not the best way.

Comment: Array of hashes? It might help if you add to your question an example of data in the table and data structure that you want to get in the end.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I edited my question to add a sample output.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. However, I am getting the following exception `undefined method 'strftime' for "2012-06-15":String`. Any idea why?

Comment: Just return this `Date.parse` thing back. Though, it works fine for me without it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you serialize your ActiveRecord::Relation to JSON (`a.to_json`) and let the JSON serializer handle the formatting of the date ?

```
Product.select("date(date) as date, count(id) as products").
  group("date(date)").to_json
```

Comment: After some searching, I'm having a hard time finding an easy way to format JSON dates.  Could you show an example of how to let the JSON serializer handle the formatting?

Comment: The previous example would format date to something like : `2012-06-16T13:53:46Z` which is what you expect unless I am wrong.

Comment: When I do `to_json`, the previous example formats as `2012-06-16` because my table specifies a `date` field instead of `datetime` field. I'll try changing that and see if I can get it to work by letting the JSON serializer handle it.

Comment: Convert your date to datetime in your ARel query and the serializer will format it with the time part.